# How to link a character to an animated armature?

Tags: rigging, particles, armature

I have an animated armature I took from Mixamo, and I would like to add it to a character I created which include hair particles, eyes and mouth, so I adjusted the armature to fit my character but beyond that i'm stuck at linking the character to the rig.

I've tried multiple ways (like converting the hair into a mesh), but couldn't find a way to make it work, often times the issue is that the hair wouldn't follow the character after converting them into a mesh, or completely disappear.

[image]

[Here is the blend file](https://ufile.io/gdlot051)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by moving the armature modifier on top of the modifiers stack after linking my character to the rig.

[image]